# Fill in specific part of triangles with colors with turtle module

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, fractals

I want to fill the triangles with the color green, except for the upside down ones, but it keeps giving me errors:

```
import turtle
import time
import random
t = turtle.Turtle()
width = 500
height = 500
Color = {"Purple":"#A46BFF","Aqua":"#56BCE8","Tree":"#5EFF7A","Summer":"#E8A83A"}
def triangle(length,draw):


    if draw==0:
    #draw the triangle
        t.color(Color.get("Aqua", "Tree"))
        for i in range(3):
            t.forward(length)
            t.left(120)
    else:
    #draws 3 triangles
        triangle(length/2,draw-1)
        t.fillcolor('Tree')
        t.begin_fill()
        t.color(Color["Tree"])
        t.fd(length/2)
        triangle(length/2,draw-1)
        t.color(Color["Summer"])
        t.bk(length/2)
        t.left(60)
        t.forward(length/2)
        t.right(60)
        triangle(length/2,draw-1)
        t.color(Color["Purple"])
        t.left(60)
        t.backward(length/2)
        t.right(60)



triangle(150,3)
window = turtle.Screen()
window.exitonclick()
```

The result I want is:

[image]

It would be nice if I could also make the triangle change color after it is drawn. For example, it will continue to put a rainbow color on the lines after it is drawn. Right now, it changes to a specific color, and once it's drawn, it stays the same. I tried to import the random module to randomize the colors dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fill the triangles with the color green, you need to do the filling in the `triangle()` function when `draw == 0`. Note that the upside down ones are just areas where nothing has been drawn, not something that's explicitly being rendered.

```
def triangle(length, draw):
    if draw == 0:
        # draw the triangle
        t.color(Color["Aqua"])
        t.fillcolor(Color["Tree"])
        t.begin_fill()
        for i in range(3):
            t.fd(length)
            t.left(120)
        t.end_fill()
    else:
        # draws 3 triangles
        triangle(length/2, draw-1)
        t.color(Color["Tree"])
        t.fd(length/2)

        triangle(length/2, draw-1)
        t.color(Color["Summer"])
        t.bk(length/2)
        t.left(60)
        t.forward(length/2)
        t.right(60)

        triangle(length/2, draw-1)
        t.color(Color["Purple"])
        t.left(60)
        t.backward(length/2)
        t.right(60)
```

Result:

[image: screenshot of properly filled-in figure]

I don't know of a way to change the color of things that are already drawn except by redrawing them completely.

Answer (score 1):

> > It would be nice if I can also make the triangle change color after it
> >     is drawned. -- @Elliot
>
> I don't know of a way to change the color of things that are already
>   drawn except by redrawing them completely. -- @martineau

I know a way, within limits:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import choice

CURSOR_SIZE = 20

COLORS = {"Purple": "#A46BFF", "Aqua": "#56BCE8", "Tree": "#5EFF7A", "Summer": "#E8A83A"}

def triangle(length, draw):
    if draw == 0:  # draw the triangle
        turtle.shapesize(length / CURSOR_SIZE)
        turtle.clone().showturtle()
    else:  # draws 3 triangles
        triangle(length/2, draw-1)

        turtle.left(60)
        turtle.forward(length/2)
        turtle.right(60)

        triangle(length/2, draw-1)

        turtle.right(60)
        turtle.forward(length/2)
        turtle.left(60)

        triangle(length/2, draw-1)

        turtle.backward(length/2)

def recolor():
    color = choice(list(COLORS.values()))

    for turtle in screen.turtles():
        turtle.color(color)

    screen.ontimer(recolor, 1000)

screen = Screen()

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.shape('triangle')
turtle.settiltangle(90)
turtle.penup()

turtle.goto(-130, -120)  # roughly center on the screen

triangle(300, 3)

recolor()

screen.exitonclick()
```

The trick here is we don't *draw* the triangles, we make each triangle its own turtle.  Then we can ask the turtles to do things, like change color, or other tricks...

[image]